# AXIOS calls and rendering data

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, axios, postman

I am new to React and AXIOS. I am trying to render data(questions assigned to a user) from an API call onto my page. Are there any limitations to running functions inside of (.then) statements?

This is my AXIOS request

```
    axios
      .get(
        "/api/v1/assigned-questions?userId=61d7d1be-4ada-4c1a-81c0-c6b82f45132e"
     )
     .then((res) => {
        // handle success
        const assignedQuestions = res.data[0];
        // object with a collection of data
        console.log(assignedQuestions);
        this.setState({ currentUser: assignedQuestions });
     })
     .catch((error) => {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitations to running functions inside of .then. .then accepts one function that's the response handler and it can execute any number of statements inside it.